# Binary search where the computer may lie upto $k$ times

Tags: algorithms

We are performing a binary search on $n$ elements where the answer to a comparison may be wrong upto $k$ times. What is the time complexity of finding the right element in terms of $n$ and $k$? The trivial upper bound is $O(k \log(n))$. Can we improve on it?

Comment: Will the test for equality always be true (i.e. of the computer tells you you've got the element you're searching for, then you've really got it)?

Comment: More generally, the test for a specific comparison could always be true or it might give different answers at different times for the same comparison. These two seems closely related since if the computer always lies at a comparision, we can easily overcome this by just asking for comparison of $(a+i < b+i) , -k/2 \leq i \leq k/2$ if we want to find whether $(a < b)$ is true in the trivial algorithm. I would appreciate an answer to both forms of the question if possible.

Comment: Have you yet considered doing an $m$-ary search instead of a binary search, for some $m > k$?